# Break on postmessage?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, postmessage

I want to be able to break on postmessage in Chrome Developer Tools, but it appears there's no such option:

[image: text]

Is it possible to conveniently break on postmessage without specifically searching the line in source code?

Edit: Someone suggested the question is a duplicate of this post: [Any good debugger for HTML5 Javascript postMessage API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053809/any-good-debugger-for-html5-javascript-postmessage-api)

The answer features Firebug extension, however, Firebug is no longer available (https://blog.getfirebug.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any good debugger for HTML5 Javascript postMessage API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053809/any-good-debugger-for-html5-javascript-postmessage-api)

Comment: While not breaking, you can see them in [the global listeners pane](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2018/05/09/attacking-postmessage-interfaces/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the browser's console, you can run `debug(window.postMessage)` there to make the execution stop when the next postMessage call is made.

Comment: I am still looking for a way to do this programmatically using the DevTools Protocol ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403514/using-the-chrome-devtools-protocol-to-log-js-function-calls)).

Comment: how do you look for incoming messages?